# Error & Warning(React Native) - Event has less arguments than mapping & ANIMATED.EVENT NOW REQUIRES A SECOND ARGUMENT FOR OPTIONS

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-animated

**Code for Animated Flatlist**

```
const scrollY = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;



const keyExtractorItem = useCallback((item) => item.id.toString(), []);



const anEvent = Animated.event(
    [
      {
        nativeEvent: {
          contentOffset: {
            y: scrollY,
          },
        },
      },
     { useNativeDriver: true }
    ],
    
  );

<AnimatedFlashList
        onScroll={anEvent}
        contentContainerStyle={{ paddingTop: StatusBar.currentHeight || 42 }}
        data={DATA}
        keyExtractor={keyExtractorItem}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        estimatedItemSize={20}
      />
```

**Error Occured While Scrolling**

> Event has less arguments than mapping

**Warning Shown**

> ANIMATED.EVENT NOW REQUIRES A SECOND ARGUMENT FOR OPTIONS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Error Solved**

```
const anEvent = Animated.event(
[
  {
    nativeEvent: {
      contentOffset: {
        y: scrollY,
      },
    },
  },
],
{ useNativeDriver: true }
```

);

> UseNativeDriver should be below the array.